# How to modify the content in android manifest file

Tags: android

When i changing the content in android manifest file it doesn't change . When i running my application it automatically realign the code . I want to know how to modify the android manifest file in my android can you please give me the solution for that

Comment: Are you editing the correct file? That is, the one under the `/src` folder, not the `/build` folder.

Comment: also clean the project and rebuild sometime this work..

Comment: Why is this question upvoted ?

Answer (score 4):

app>>manifest>>AndoirdManifest.xml 
The manifest file presents essential information about your app to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the app's code.

Answer (score 1):

AndroidManifest is not auto-generated so you can edit and save it.

Close all current tabs e open directly the AndroidManifest again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

{
"format_version": 2,

```
"header": {
    "description": "Splahmc server",
    "name": "Splashmc server",
    "uuid": "e5f5c938-a701-11eb-b2a3-047d7bb283ba",
    "version": [1, 0, 6],
    "min_engine_version": [ 1, 16, 0 ]
},
"modules": [
    {
        "description": "GeyserOptionalPack",
        "type": "resources",
        "uuid": "eebb4ea8-a701-11eb-95ba-047d7bb283ba",
        "version": [1, 0, 6]
    }
]
```

}